# Any review articles on behavior change psychology?

Tags: reference-request, motivation, health-psychology

I'm interested in behavior change and looking to apply its principals in order to design programs and services in healthcare. I'm most familiar with [BJ Fogg's B=MAT model](http://www.behaviormodel.org/) and his principles.
But I'd love to get suggestions that let me go deeper into this topic and how it can tie into applied work.

**What are good review articles on behavioural change psychology?**

Answer (score 6):

**Elder et al (1999)** provides a review of behavioural change theories in the context of health behavior change in primary care. They mention several, for example:

> Models and theories such as the Health Belief Model,
>   Cognitive/Information Processing, the Theory of Reasoned
>   Action, Social Cognitive (Learning) Theory,Social Support
>   Theories, Behavior Modiﬁcation, and Kanfer’s Parallel
>   Self-Management Model guide much of current health-promotion reFsearch and practice. The 
>   Transtheoretical or “Stages of Change” Model presents a cognitive-behavioral
>   change process not grounded in a speciic health behavior theory.

**Green (1984)** provides a very general review of health behavior modification.

**Stokols (1992)** presents a theory around healthy environments.

#### References

- Elder, J. P., Ayala, G. X., & Harris, S. (1999). Theories and intervention approaches to health-behavior change in primary care. American journal of preventive medicine, 17(4), 275-284. [PDF](ftp://filer.soc.uoc.gr/Psycho/Manola/2008-09/%E8%E5%F9%F1%DF%E5%F2%20%F3%F5%EC%F0%E5%F1%E9%F6%EF%F1%FE%ED%20%EA%E1%E9%20%F5%E3%E5%DF%E1/health%20behaviour%20change%20approaches.pdf)
- Green, L. W. (1984). Modifying and developing health behavior. Annual review of public health, 5(1), 215-236. [PDF](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.pu.05.050184.001243)
- Stokols, D. (1992). Establishing and maintaining healthy environments: toward a social ecology of health promotion. American Psychologist, 47(1), 6. [PDF](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/21615651_Establishing_and_maintaining_healthy_environments._Toward_a_social_ecology_of_health_promotion/file/3deec51648b8bb0531.pdf)